# ffmpeg Config to Produce H.264 Constrained Baseline Profile

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, video-quality

It all begins with Plex and appears to end at ffmpeg as the easiest possible solution.  I love ffmpeg!  I use Plex running on Linux to stream over home network to a Roku.  I've used this for years until recently as I'll describe below.  I have a temporary workaround using Chromecast to bypass this issue.

**Some videos don't play.** There are two differences between the ones that play and the ones that don'that (**sound but black screen**).  I list these below.  Another possibility not listed is that Roku / Plex / Ubuntu have some kind of interaction (bug).  Maybe the Roku device is old and unsupported?  I listed my config way below.

1. ffmpeg used to generate mkv / mp4 for the ones that don't play (sound but black screen).   Handbrake and WinxDVD used to generate mkv / m4a for the ones that do play.  My ffmpeg command is:

`**ffmpeg -threads 4 -f gdigrab -probesize 42M -thread_queue_size 1024 -i desktop -f dshow -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" -vf scale=720:404 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -t   6.0 -y  "C:/Users/daveg/Documents/Recordings\trial4_raw.mp4"**`

2. Video file properties show **codec H.264 High 4:4:4** for the ones that don't play (sound but black screen). and **H.264 Constrained Baseline Profile** for the ones that do play.

**Does somebody know how to configure ffmpeg to generate H.264 Constrained Baseline Profile?** That seems like my next logical step. I tried various crf values only to produce grainy results still with High 4:4:4 nature.

Plex 1.32.8.7639 running on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Roku 3920X s/w 12.5.0 build 4178-91

ffmpeg 4.4.2 running on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not actually need baseline profile, but only a compatible pixel format i.e. YUV 4:2:0 as opposed to YUV 4:4:4 that ffmpeg converts gdigrab's RGB frames to.

Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. For baseline profile, also add `-profile:v baseline`.

Comment: `-pix_fmt yuv420` added just after `libx264` did the trick.  No longer have black screen with sound for Plex on Roku.  When I type `ffmpeg -pix_fmts` I find a whole list of these options...research for another day.  Thanks.   I didn't try the `-profile:v baseline` suggestion.  Another day.